# How to place differently sized images in 2 columns with figcaption aligned

Tags: html, css, image, position, center

Sorry if this is a trivial question, I am 'new' to programming in general but here goes:

So I am making a Portfolio page as an exercise, but I can't solve the following problem.

I got 6 figures, all contain an img (which are links) and a figcaption. I am trying to place these in 2 columns - in these 2 columns the images should be centered with their figcaption.

I have tried several methods: trying to make images inline-blocks, trying to make 2 divs for the 2 columns, trying to use the Bootstrap grid system but I always end up with the following problem.

When on full page view, the smaller images (in width) have some "autopadding" added to them, so the area around them also becomes a link + the figcaption is not displayed under them. I am guessing this is they are displayed as an inline block. No matter how I try, this happens every time.

I known there must be an easy solution for this, but I just can't seem to find it. Any advice please?

To better understand the issue, here is a link to the site I am talking about:
http://codepen.io/Bubicica/pen/RRaaze (note it looks OK here, this is how I want it to look)
http://codepen.io/Bubicica/full/RRaaze/ (here 'Project fuzzy' looks pretty bad and shows the problem)

Here is the the (one of the) CSS(s) and (one of the) HTML(s) that I am using:

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

figcaption {
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

<figure>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N42X5dljQGk" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" class="img-responsive kitten" id="img1"></a>
      <figcaption>Project Fur
      </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYXlFYBW56g&feature=youtu.be" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/310/330" class="img-responsive kitten" id="img2"></a>
    <figcaption>Project Warm
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Edit: setting Width to auto or not setting at all for figure gives me the right aligning but then the images are not aligned under each other in the right (second) column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the easiest solution to your problem would be to use Flexbox (`display: flex`) on the items as it allows for very high customization of the alignment of things. The best resource for this for me has has been CSS-Tricks' guide, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). After reading that, I'm confident you'll have enough of an understanding of it to be able to apply it to your problem here.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went with this method, and I actually realized that what I have imagined is actually impossible but this got me the closest to it. These flexboxes are really useful, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. The image won't allow itself to be centered since you define it as block, so reset that. Remove your left margin from `figure` (add spacing via `padding`) and set the entire thing to `border-box` so padding is absorbed into calculated width. Float those left and for even numbered `figure` clear the float so you don't get a jagged flow after tall figures.

```
.img-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
}

figure {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    /* margin-left: 12%; */
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

figure:nth-child(even) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Make sure to wrap all this in the appropriate media query for whatever display you are targeting.

Comment: Thank you, a very good solution and did solve the problem but I went with the flexboxes in the end because that was brand new for me.

Comment: No worries, whatever works best for you. An upvote is appreciated, but no biggie.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upvote things here :(